# difference between pty and a pipe

Tags: terminal, pipe, pty

I have been reading about ptys from this page's example: http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html. I have two questions:

- What is the difference, or the most important difference, between using a pty and using  a pipe? From what I have read, both are for inter-process communication, but with a pty the process can "treat it like a normal terminal". What does that mean?
- What is a "controlling terminal"? I have read about them but can't understand what they really are. Is the controlling terminal always the pty assigned to the process?

Comment: Is my question a bad one? I don't see an answer and was wondering if I asked something wrong

Comment: No, your question is a good one (I remember wondering about it myself). It is very broad, however, and difficult to answer non-technically, while the article you mention is already very good. I'll try to give an answer below

Comment: For PTYs, also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html) you mention is excellent, and hard to improve upon, but it is rather technical. I'll try to give a less technical explanation (bear with me, Unix gurus!)

A **pipe** is just an unidirectional data channel: it can only be written on one end, and read on the other.  For bidirectional inter-process communication you'll always need *two* pipes. Pipes are excellent to move bits around, but not for much more.

A **pty** (pseudoterminal) can be read and written on both ends, but it is much more than just a bidirectional data channel. To understand this, it is useful to have a look at a real terminal: On one end there is a process reading keystrokes and sending characters to a teletype or screen. On the other end there is a real human banging away at a keyboard and staring at the above-mentioned screen. Only one end has a file descriptor, the other end is just a connector and a cable.

Historically, terminals have developed many attributes that can be controlled by the programs running on them (like 'echo mode' or 'canonical mode', see `termios (3)`) Also, a terminal can let the user (by way of the above-mentioned connector and cable) send signals that can be used for 'job control', e.g. by typing CTRL-Z to put a foreground job in the background.

A `pty` is like a real terminal where *both ends* are file descriptors:

- the *slave end* behaves exactly like a real terminal : a process that has a descriptor for the slave end ("inferior process") can read from, and write to it, but also set terminal attibutes like echo mode or the interrupt character (e.g. CTRL+C). It will usually not even be aware that is is not connected to a real screen and keyboard.
- the *master end* looks more like a keyboard and teletype for use, not by humans, but by other processes: any process that has opened the the master end can write to it, and will receive echo (but only if the inferior process has set the `ECHO` attribute on the slave). It can also (on most modern unices) control the session that has the slave as its *controlling terminal*), e.g. by sending CTRL+Z.

To understand what a **controlling terminal** is, it is again useful to think about the scenario where a real user is logged in at a real terminal. The user can start a "session", i.e. a collection of processes, some of them in foreground jobs, others in the background.

To prevent chaos, a controlling terminal (i.e. the kernel structure associated with it) keeps track of which processes are in a foreground or background job, and which processes are allowed to read from and write to it. Whenever a process tries something illegal (like a background process reading from the controlling terminal) the operation will fail (with `EIO`) and the whole job is then stopped by the kernel (using the signal `SIGTTIN`)

This shows that, just as with a real terminal, only the slave end of a pty can be a controlling terminal, and that the concept only makes sense on a Unix system that supports  job control (any Unix system, nowadays)

Comment: I understand better now, I am just a little confused with the controling terminal, is the controling terminal any process conected to the slave or is the slave the controling terminal?

Comment: A process is never called a "terminal". The slave end of a pty can be the controlling terminal of a session. The oldest process in a session is called the "session leader" (it will often be some kind of shell) and usually (but not necessarily) it is the process that instructs the controlling terminal to put other process groups in the background or foreground. In a sense you could call this process the "terminal controller", but never the "controlling terminal"

Comment: Oh I see The pty is like a virtual terminal program that manage how programs interact and use the resources

Comment: Pardon me if i dont grasp the concept pretty well is not easy for me but your explanation is really good

Comment: Note the rather important bit in this answer and in the linked article: The master side is *not* a terminal! So if you, like me, expected canonical read()s on the master side, well, it won't happen :-(